# Is it possible to set localStorage or Session variable in asp.net page and read it in javascript on the other page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, local-storage, session-variables

As in question. Is it possible to set variable in asp.net page in localStorage and retrieve it on the other page?

How to set localStorage variable in asp.net. Is it possible?
After that I could read variable using:

```
localStorage.getItem('UserID');
```

Comment: Local storage isn't ASP.NET, it's a web browser API. You use javascript to work with it.  As to your Session question, you can always make a request to the server to get any value you might generally want, if you've built something to answer those requests. So... what's your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess You can't. The whole point of local storage is that it is local and You can manipulate it only from javascript. If You need to pass values between server and client You need to use some transport technology - cookies, ajax calls, hidden fields etc. It will all depend on how your application is organized, what kind of information is being stored, its volume, whether you want to redirect or not, but in all cases this should be done using javascript since that's the only way to access data stored in localStorage.

Comment: string myScriptValue = "function callMe() {alert('You pressed Me!'); }";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myScriptName", myScriptValue, true);   But i dont think mixing code behind and javascript is a good idea - just a sugestion. Anytime you need to make a simple change/update to your javascript you'll have to re-build your project, which means re-deploying instead of simply pushing out a single .js file.

Comment: I've tried this way, but it needs Postback. In my case it isn't possible. Thanks for answers ;)

Comment: you can output Javascript from ASP .Net so anything that can be done in Javascript can be done in ASP .Net

Answer (score 9):

Old post yes, but knowledge is always good.

You can set the local or session storage from asp.net (indirectly). Since we can set up javascript code in asp.net and insert into the client side, there's no difference with the session or local storage.

Try this from server side

```
string script = string.Format("sessionStorage.userId= '{0}';", "12345");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

That will set the session (you could do local) storage variable to the value 12345.

Answer (score 5):

I've done this by using cookies:

Default.aspx.cs code behind:

```
HttpCookie userIdCookie = new HttpCookie("UserID");
userIdCookie.Value = id.ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(userIdCookie);
Response.Redirect("~/ImagePage.html");
```

HttpCookie Expires wasn't setted. It expires default with session.

html page javascript:

```
function OnLoad() {
var userId = getCookie('UserdID');
if (userId == null)
    window.location = "http://localhost:53566/Default.aspx";        
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie;
    var cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf(" " + cookieName + "=");
    if (cookieStart == -1) {
        cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf("=");
    }
    if (cookieStart == -1) {
        cookieValue = null;
    }
    else {
        cookieStart = cookieValue.indexOf("=", cookieStart) + 1;
        var cookieEnd = cookieValue.indexOf(";", cookieStart);
        if (cookieEnd == -1) {
            cookieEnd = cookieValue.length;
        }
        cookieValue = unescape(cookieValue.substring(cookieStart, cookieEnd));
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think setting session variable in page & read variable in javascript of another page is possible. But, if you are looking out for localstorage that won't be. It needs javascript. For session variable e.g.
A.aspx

> <% Session["username"]="Donald Duck"; %>

B.aspx

```
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>       var user = "<%= Session["username"] %>";
>       document.write(user);
>  </script>
```

Comment: The second page isn't .aspx page, but html + js only.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible in html+js too.

Answer (score 2):

A pure C# solution is currently available using Asp.Net Core and Blazor components with [`ProtectedBrowserStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#browser-storage-server).

- Add a blazor component to the project
- Inject `ProtectedLocalStorage` or `ProtectedSessionStorage` into the component
- Use `GetAsync<T>` and `SetAsync<T>` methods to store and retrive data from local storage. Any object type can be used with T.
- Blazor components can be used inside Razor Pages and MVC projects as well.

#### Set Local Storage Component

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage LocalStorage

<button @onclick="async ()=> await SaveToLocalStorageAsync()">Save</button>

@code {
    private const string _localStorage = "MyLocalStorage";

    private async Task SaveToLocalStorageAsync()
    {
        await LocalStorage.SetAsync<string>(_localStorage, "text to be saved");
    }
}
```

#### Read Local Storage Component

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage LocalStorage

<p>@TxtFromLocalStorage</p>

@code {
    private string TxtFromLocalStorage = string.Empty;
    private const string _localStorage = "MyLocalStorage";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var result = await LocalStorage.GetAsync<string>(_localStorage);
        TxtFromLocalStorage = result.Success ? result.Value : "Can't read local storage";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `asp:HiddenField`

after changed `localstorage` or `sessionStorage` you fill hidden field and use in code behind.