# set the local storage via asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, local-storage, session-variables, .net-5

I am searching for a way to store and read local storage from asp.net core web application.

Suppose the user manages counties. It has a `currentCountry`.
Actually the `currentCountryId` is stored in a session variable, but the session ends often and the `currentCountry` object became invalid. Not good. Is there a way to store the currentCountryId in the browser local storage, in asp.net core?

Comment: I don’t know why this question is closed as duplicate of 9 years old one! Simply using a Blazor component makes it possible to store data into local storage. You can add a blazor component to your existing Asp.Net Core (MVC or Razor Pages) app and use [protected browser storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#aspnet-core-protected-browser-storage) to store and retrive data from the local storage. You don’t even need any javascript to do so. I will post an answer there tomorrow :)

Comment: I posted [an answer in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354740/5519026) and voted to reopen this question, since I believe things changed a lot now.